# Why sum of all process CPU(%) is not equal to total cpu(%) utilisation in top output

Tags: cpu, monitoring, top

In the attached image of top command output, you can see the idle is 96.8% means CPU utilisation is 3.2% but, sum of CPU% of all the process listed (Image cropped for CPU% > 0.0) is more than the total utilised (3.2%)

[image: TOP Command output]

And in another top instance, the CPU utilisation (100-idle) was 14% but the top most process shown "Chrome" alone consumes 253%. I am unsure of how the chrome process consumes CPU more than 100%

Help me with the interpretation of top output if I am wrong

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 4):

That isn't what the "CPU(s)" column shows. From `man top`:

> ```
>    Line 2 shows CPU state percentages based on  the  interval  since  the
>    last refresh.
>
>    As   a  default,  percentages  for  these  individual  categories  are
>    displayed.  Where two labels are shown below, those  for  more  recent
>    kernel versions are shown first.
>        us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
>        sy, system  : time running kernel processes
>        ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
>        id, idle    : time spent in the kernel idle handler
>        wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
>        hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
>        si : time spent servicing software interrupts
>        st : time stolen from this vm by the hypervisor
> ```

So when you see that 98.8%, that doesn't mean 98.8% of available CPU power. It is telling you what percentage of *time* the CPU spent in each of those categories since the last time `top` polled the system. By default, `top` polls the system every 2 seconds. So your line is telling you that your CPU spent most of the last 2 seconds in an idle state.

I have posted a fuller description of how `top` works here: https://superuser.com/a/575330/151431.

Answer (score 2):

It is my (very basic) understanding that the CPU consumption in the header is percentage of total CPU (all CPUs/cores), whereas the `%CPU` in the table is (by default) percentage per CPU/core.

This means that the sum of the percentages in the table *divided by the number of CPUs/cores in your system* should roughly match the CPU consumption in the header.

Further, the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/top.1.html) states:

> ```
> 1. %CPU  --  CPU Usage
>    The  task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a
>    percentage of total CPU time.
>
>    In a true SMP environment, if a process is multi-threaded and top is not operating  in
>    Threads mode, amounts greater than 100% may be reported.  You toggle Threads mode with
>    the `H' interactive command.
>
>    Also for multi-processor environments, if Irix  mode  is  Off,  top  will  operate  in
>    Solaris  mode  where  a  task's cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs.
>    You toggle Irix/Solaris modes with the `I' interactive command.
> ```

You can see in the last paragraph that if you press `I` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>), you switch to a mode where the CPU time for each process is divided by the number of CPUs/cores. In this mode, the total of the table should match the number in the header.

###### Examples from my own system with 4 cores

Irix mode **on** (default) - sum in the table is roughly 4 times total in header.

[image]

Irix mode **off** (Solaris mode) - sum in the table is roughly the same as in header.

[image]

Also, see @terdon's answer as to why the numbers aren't exactly the same - and add to that rounding of fractions etc.

###### Disabling Irix mode in batch operation

To disable Irix mode in batch operation, do the following:

1. Run `top` in normal mode
2. Disable Irix mode with: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
3. Save a configuration file for the current user: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

The configuration file will be located at `$HOME/.config/procps`

Now, when you run top for this user (including batch mode), Irix mode will be disabled.

To make this the default for the `root` user, switch to root (with `sudo -s`) and run the 3 steps above.

*Since top is a relatively simple program, it's not possible to run with a custom config file. If you require custom config or CPU metrics, consider using another method than top output.*